# AI in tic Tac Toe not moving random

Tags: android, random

I am changing the concept to 3x3 Tic Tac Toe to 9x9. concept is just like TicTacToe you have to win horizontal vertical or diagonal 3 spots only difference is That I have divided the game into 9 sets when a person wins a particular set that marks as a single spot for that person, now he/she has to win next sets to win the main game.
now to the problem i am facing game is working fine AI is generating random numbers till human or computer wins the first set after that AI moves are not random they are in a sequence.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class TicTacToeGame {

private char mBoard[];
private final static int BOARD_SIZE = 81;

public static final char PLAYER_ONE = 'X';
public static final char PLAYER_TWO = '0';
public static final char EMPTY_SPACE = ' ';

private Random mRand;


public static int getBOARD_SIZE() {
    // Return the size of the board
    return BOARD_SIZE;
}

public TicTacToeGame(){

    mBoard = new char[BOARD_SIZE];

    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++)
        mBoard[i] = EMPTY_SPACE;

    mRand = new Random();
}

// Clear the board of all X's and O's
public void clearBoard()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < BOARD_SIZE; i++)
    {
        mBoard[i] = EMPTY_SPACE;
    }
}

// set the given player at the given location on the game board.
// the location must be available, or the board will not be changed.
public void setMove(char player, int location)
{
    mBoard[location] = player;
}

// Return the best move for the computer to make. You must call setMove()
// to actually make the computer move to that location.
public int getComputerMove()
{
    int move;

    // First see if there's a move O can make to win
    for (int i = 0; i < getBOARD_SIZE(); i++)
    {
        if (mBoard[i] != PLAYER_ONE && mBoard[i] != PLAYER_TWO)
        {
            char curr = mBoard[i];
            mBoard[i] = PLAYER_TWO;
            if (checkForWinner() == 3)
            {
                setMove(PLAYER_TWO, i);
                return i;
            }
            else
                mBoard[i] = curr;
        }
    }

    // See if there's a move O can make to block X from winning
    for (int i = 0; i < getBOARD_SIZE(); i++)
    {
        if (mBoard[i] != PLAYER_ONE && mBoard[i] != PLAYER_TWO)
        {
            char curr = mBoard[i];
            mBoard[i] = PLAYER_ONE;
            if (checkForWinner() == 2)
            {
                setMove(PLAYER_TWO, i);
                return i;
            }
            else
                mBoard[i] = curr;
        }
    }

    // Generate random move
    do
    {
        move = mRand.nextInt(getBOARD_SIZE());
    } while (mBoard[move] == PLAYER_ONE || mBoard[move] == PLAYER_TWO);

    setMove(PLAYER_TWO, move);
    return move;
}

// Check for a winner and return a status value indicating who has won.
// Return 0 if no winner or tie yet, 1 if it's a tie, 2 if X won, or 3
// if O won.
public int checkForWinner()
{
    //set0 win chk
    if ((mBoard[0] == PLAYER_ONE &&
            mBoard[1] == PLAYER_ONE &&
            mBoard[2] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[9] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[10] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[11] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[18] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[19] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[20] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[0] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[9] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[18] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[1] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[10] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[19] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[2] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[11] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[20] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[0] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[10] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[20] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[2] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[10] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[18] == PLAYER_ONE))
        return 2;

    if ((mBoard[0] == PLAYER_TWO &&
            mBoard[1] == PLAYER_TWO &&
            mBoard[2] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[9] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[10] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[11] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[18] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[19] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[20] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[0] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[9] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[18] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[1] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[10] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[19] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[2] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[11] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[20] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[0] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[10] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[20] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[2] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[10] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[18] == PLAYER_TWO))
        return 3;

    //set1 win chk
    if ((mBoard[3] == PLAYER_ONE &&
            mBoard[4] == PLAYER_ONE &&
            mBoard[5] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[12] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[13] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[14] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[21] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[22] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[23] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[3] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[12] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[21] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[4] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[13] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[22] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[5] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[14] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[23] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[3] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[13] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[23] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[5] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[13] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[21] == PLAYER_ONE))
        return 2;

    if ((mBoard[3] == PLAYER_TWO &&
            mBoard[4] == PLAYER_TWO &&
            mBoard[5] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[12] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[13] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[14] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[21] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[22] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[23] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[3] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[12] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[21] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[4] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[13] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[22] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[5] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[14] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[23] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[3] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[13] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[23] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[5] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[13] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[21] == PLAYER_TWO))
        return 3;

    //set2 win chk
    if ((mBoard[6] == PLAYER_ONE &&
            mBoard[7] == PLAYER_ONE &&
            mBoard[8] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[15] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[16] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[17] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[24] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[25] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[26] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[6] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[15] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[24] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[7] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[16] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[25] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[8] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[17] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[26] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[6] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[16] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[26] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[8] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[16] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[24] == PLAYER_ONE))
        return 2;

    if ((mBoard[6] == PLAYER_TWO &&
            mBoard[7] == PLAYER_TWO &&
            mBoard[8] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[15] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[16] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[17] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[24] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[25] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[26] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[6] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[15] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[24] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[7] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[16] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[25] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[8] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[17] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[26] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[6] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[16] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[26] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[8] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[16] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[24] == PLAYER_TWO))
        return 3;

    //set3 win chk
    if ((mBoard[27] == PLAYER_ONE &&
            mBoard[28] == PLAYER_ONE &&
            mBoard[29] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[36] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[37] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[38] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[45] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[46] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[47] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[27] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[36] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[45] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[28] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[37] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[46] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[29] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[38] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[47] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[27] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[37] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[47] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[29] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[37] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[45] == PLAYER_ONE))
        return 2;

    if ((mBoard[27] == PLAYER_TWO &&
            mBoard[28] == PLAYER_TWO &&
            mBoard[29] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[36] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[37] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[38] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[45] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[46] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[47] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[27] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[36] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[45] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[28] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[37] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[46] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[29] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[38] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[47] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[27] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[37] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[47] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[29] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[37] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[45] == PLAYER_TWO))
        return 3;

    //set4 win chk
    if ((mBoard[30] == PLAYER_ONE &&
            mBoard[31] == PLAYER_ONE &&
            mBoard[32] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[39] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[40] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[41] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[48] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[49] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[50] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[30] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[39] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[48] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[31] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[40] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[49] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[32] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[41] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[50] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[30] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[40] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[50] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[32] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[40] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[48] == PLAYER_ONE))
        return 2;

    if ((mBoard[30] == PLAYER_TWO &&
            mBoard[31] == PLAYER_TWO &&
            mBoard[32] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[39] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[40] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[41] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[48] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[49] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[50] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[30] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[39] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[48] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[31] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[40] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[49] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[32] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[41] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[50] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[30] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[40] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[50] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[32] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[40] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[48] == PLAYER_TWO))
        return 3;

    //set5 win chk
    if ((mBoard[33] == PLAYER_ONE &&
            mBoard[34] == PLAYER_ONE &&
            mBoard[35] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[42] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[43] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[44] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[51] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[52] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[53] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[33] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[48] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[51] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[34] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[43] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[52] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[35] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[44] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[53] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[33] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[43] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[53] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[53] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[43] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[51] == PLAYER_ONE))
        return 2;

    if ((mBoard[33] == PLAYER_TWO &&
            mBoard[34] == PLAYER_TWO &&
            mBoard[35] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[42] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[43] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[44] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[51] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[52] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[53] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[33] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[48] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[51] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[34] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[43] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[52] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[35] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[44] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[53] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[33] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[43] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[53] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[53] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[43] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[51] == PLAYER_TWO))
        return 3;

    //set6 win chk
    if ((mBoard[54] == PLAYER_ONE &&
            mBoard[55] == PLAYER_ONE &&
            mBoard[56] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[63] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[64] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[65] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[72] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[73] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[74] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[54] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[63] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[72] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[55] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[64] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[73] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[56] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[65] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[74] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[54] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[64] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[74] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[56] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[64] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[72] == PLAYER_ONE))
        return 2;

    if ((mBoard[54] == PLAYER_TWO &&
            mBoard[55] == PLAYER_TWO &&
            mBoard[56] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[63] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[64] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[65] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[72] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[73] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[74] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[54] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[63] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[72] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[55] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[64] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[73] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[56] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[65] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[74] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[54] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[64] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[74] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[56] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[64] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[72] == PLAYER_TWO))
        return 3;

    //set7 win chk
    if ((mBoard[57] == PLAYER_ONE &&
            mBoard[58] == PLAYER_ONE &&
            mBoard[59] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[66] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[67] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[68] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[75] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[76] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[77] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[57] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[66] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[75] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[58] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[67] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[76] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[59] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[68] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[77] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[57] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[67] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[77] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[59] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[67] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[75] == PLAYER_ONE))
        return 2;

    if ((mBoard[57] == PLAYER_TWO &&
            mBoard[58] == PLAYER_TWO &&
            mBoard[59] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[66] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[67] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[68] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[75] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[76] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[77] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[57] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[66] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[75] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[58] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[67] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[76] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[59] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[68] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[77] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[57] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[67] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[77] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[59] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[67] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[75] == PLAYER_TWO))
        return 3;

    //set8 win chk
    if ((mBoard[60] == PLAYER_ONE &&
            mBoard[61] == PLAYER_ONE &&
            mBoard[62] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[69] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[70] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[71] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[78] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[79] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[80] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[60] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[69] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[78] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[61] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[70] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[79] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[62] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[71] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[80] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[60] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[70] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[80] == PLAYER_ONE) ||
            (mBoard[62] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[70] == PLAYER_ONE &&
                    mBoard[78] == PLAYER_ONE))
        return 2;

    if ((mBoard[60] == PLAYER_TWO &&
            mBoard[61] == PLAYER_TWO &&
            mBoard[62] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[69] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[70] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[71] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[78] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[79] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[80] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[60] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[69] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[78] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[61] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[70] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[79] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[62] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[71] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[80] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[60] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[70] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[80] == PLAYER_TWO) ||
            (mBoard[62] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[70] == PLAYER_TWO &&
                    mBoard[78] == PLAYER_TWO))
        return 3;

    // Check for a tie
    for (int i = 0; i < getBOARD_SIZE(); i++)
    {
        // if we find a number, then no one has won yet
        if (mBoard[i] != PLAYER_ONE && mBoard[i] != PLAYER_TWO)
            return 0;
    }

    // If we make it through the previous loop, all places are taken, so it's a tie
    return 1;
}
}
```

attaching a pic to show what is going on

[Showing the steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFC59.jpg)

the MainActivity.java is to big to put here and it is working fine because when I remove the following piece of code from the function getComputerMove() from the TicTacToeGame.java file which is shared above the random number works fine. But then AI never tries to win or stop us from winning.

```
 // First see if there's a move O can make to win
 for (int i = 0; i < getBOARD_SIZE(); i++)
 {
    if (mBoard[i] != PLAYER_ONE && mBoard[i] != PLAYER_TWO)
    {
        char curr = mBoard[i];
        mBoard[i] = PLAYER_TWO;
        if (checkForWinner() == 3)
        {
            setMove(PLAYER_TWO, i);
            return i;
        }
        else
            mBoard[i] = curr;
    }
}

// See if there's a move O can make to block X from winning
for (int i = 0; i < getBOARD_SIZE(); i++)
{
    if (mBoard[i] != PLAYER_ONE && mBoard[i] != PLAYER_TWO)
    {
        char curr = mBoard[i];
        mBoard[i] = PLAYER_ONE;
        if (checkForWinner() == 2)
        {
            setMove(PLAYER_TWO, i);
            return i;
        }
        else
            mBoard[i] = curr;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is something totaly wrong with your code design. You dont need that much if-conditions. Think about loops...

Comment: each has to give different information at the end so loop is not for me at the moment

Comment: _so loop is not for me at the moment_ Well it is, you just dont want to see it

Comment: Perfect example of how you should redesign the code when something scales ...

Comment: there are 9 sets and each if is for one set when we win a set it will generate the info which will point out who won which set and after that the function will check who won the game. so according to my very little knowledge in java i cant see how loop will help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the AI acts in a sequence because of your check for a winning move.

```
// First see if there's a move O can make to win
for (int i = 0; i < getBOARD_SIZE(); i++)
{
    if (mBoard[i] != PLAYER_ONE && mBoard[i] != PLAYER_TWO)
    {
        char curr = mBoard[i];
        mBoard[i] = PLAYER_TWO;
        if (checkForWinner() == 3)
        {
            setMove(PLAYER_TWO, i);
            return i;
        }
        else
            mBoard[i] = curr;
    }
}
```

[image: Your AI saw this as a winning move]
So the AI will continue making these horizontal moves in a sequence beccause they all count as winning moves.

You may want to consider using multiple one or two dimensional arrays to represent each mini Tic-Tac-Toe game

Comment: if I consider each set as an individual will it move in every set simultaneously or will it only move in the same set where we have clicked

Comment: Well, you could randomly choose a set where the AI should play, or you could have the AI's moves be limited to a particular set.

Comment: i dont want to restrict to one set whole board is open for playing

Comment: I understand that, so you could generate a random number between 1 and 9 and the random number would represent the set wherein the AI would make a move.